# How to create a gallery with different states

Tags: javascript, arrays, actionlistener

I have a gallery page with four different sections: art, tattoo, info and gallery. The first image of each is displayed in a DIV called imageWrap when the headings are clicked, while the arrow icons (visible on section highlight) cycle through the images and notes via variables which reference a number of arrays.

I want to make the arrow buttons reference the correct variable set dependending on which section is active. Is there a way to listen for the current gallery state and modify the action listeners to handle the correct variable?

The page with the issue is located here:
[www.christopherwynne.com/tattoo](http://www.christopherwynne.com/tattoo)

I am still fairly new at Java, and any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Short answer "No" with your code. you have to start with Javascript basics (not java). I strongly suggest you to read Javascript the good part book by D.Crockford. trust me it's worth to spare that time.

Comment: toggle classes on elements within click or other event handlers

Comment: @charlietfl - Your solution sounds practical. Should I toggle the classes of the arrow divs to make them into new classes which reference a different set of listeners - for instance 'tattooArrow' references 'tattooListener')?

Comment: @risyasin Thanks for the resource. I definitely need a more thorough understanding of many core principles.

Answer (score 0):

Well i suggest you learn some Javascript Basics to develop more attractive webpages, i don't think java work on here for doing.

if you don't know anything about Javascript i leave you this resource

[Javascript its sexy](http://javascriptissexy.com)

JSIS give you the best resource to learn property JS, also give you another tutorials for learn some others frameworks like Meteor

Also if you say "i don't have time to learn JS i need my tattoo web page and the gallery image working" take a look on this page

[Codrops Images Galley](http://tympanus.net/codrops/?s=images)

Its very easy to adapt to the current web and look pretty nice

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the resources, and your thoughts on the look of the page. I have been excited about learning more Java fundamentals ever since I worked with Flash Actionscript, and I am still trying to bridge the gap between my knowledge and the type of coding that runs plugins such as the ones found on the codrops page you mentioned. I've also been told that CSS can produce many of the same effects I am looking for, so I am going to have to do a lot more research!